# What's the measure of the segment $BF$ in the question below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the hexagon equiangle ABCDEF in which:
$DE= 2BC$ and $EF = 2CD$.

Calculate $BF$, and we also know that BD =$\sqrt3$

Resolution by geometry

My progress:
Try to make the figure as close as possible in function of the data...I don't know if it's correct...and I drew some auxiliary lines

$\triangle IJK$ is equlateral

Get lost in this exercise...I can't see much useful relationships

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\triangle DEF \sim \triangle BCD$ and $DF = 2 DB$

Also, $\angle BDF = 60^0$. Can you show how?

As $DF$ is twice $DB$ and angle between them is $60^\circ$, what does that tell about $\triangle DBF$ and hence what is the value of $BF$?

Comment: yes...I understand everything...and I arrived at the solution by the law of cosines ( ($BF = 3$). Is that right or is there another way without using trigonometry?

Comment: There is no need for trigonometry. If you draw two line segments from a point such that one of them is double of the other and angle between them is $60^\circ$, then joining the vertices will always make a right triangle. So by Pythagoras, $BF^2 = (2 \sqrt3)^2 - (\sqrt 3)^2 = 9 \implies BF = 3$

Comment: "*There is no need for trigonometry*". No, that *is* trigonometry. : )

Comment: @ACB yes yes in a way yes :) but if we make $60^\circ$ angle at the other end and complete an equilateral triangle of sides $2 \sqrt3$. The midpoint of a side gives $\sqrt3$ and the height is then what we are seeking which can be obtained by Pythagoras. The question is how far one wants to really go to avoid trigonometry and why! Sometimes it is easier to just use simple trigonometry mixed with a geometric solution.

Comment: grateful..we are used to seeing the relationship of the sides with the right angle that ends up going unnoticed when only the other remarkable angle with the sides appears

Comment: @ACB personally I have nothing against trigonometry even because the resolution would be correct in the same way with its use...I just try to be coherent with the book that does not use the same...if the problem is posted, it is because it is possible to resolution by geometry and in a way it would be of great help in the development of those who like the subject to seek resolution through it

Comment: @MathLover personally I have nothing against trigonometry even because the resolution would be correct in the same way with its use...I just try to be coherent with the book that does not use the same...if the problem is posted, it is because it is possible to resolution by geometry and in a way it would be of great help in the development of those who like the subject to seek resolution through it